# Marketo client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a client side script in WordPress to listen to the Marketo lead DB side:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('#ext-0000 .x-combo-list-item:contains("something")').click(function() {
var $this = $j(this);

alert("You have selected Something!");

// Ajax call
ajaxConnection($this);
});
```

So basically, if a Marketo Admin goes into the Marketo dashboard and selects from the combo box,"something", alert the user.

Is it possible to do this or what's a better way to do it?

Thanks,
rolu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is possible.  But to get information out of Marketo requires the SOAP (or soon RESTful) API.  So you'd have the javascript call some webservice using ajax and get a response client side, but using the server side methods.  Does that make sense?